# Haskell (formidably long) palindrome check

Tags: list, haskell, ghc, ghci, palindrome

I'm working my way up the infamous [H-99 problems](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/H-99%3a_Ninety-Nine_Haskell_Problems) and I'm playing around [problem #6](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions/1_to_10) (find out whether a list is a palindrome). I understand most solutions will work on reasonably well on reasonably short lists. Now how would I write a function to test if a *very* long list is a palindrome, e.g.,

```
let ll = [1..10000000] ++ [10000000, 10000000-1..1] ++ [7]
```

I (naively perhaps) tried to test it as such:

```
isPalindrome [] = True
isPalindrome [_] = True
isPalindrome [x,y] = x==y
isPalindrome (x:xs) = isPalindrome [x,last xs] && (isPalindrome $ init xs)
```

where I'm assuming that if `isPalindrome [x,last xs]` evaluates to `False`, the expensive right hand side of `&&` will not be evaluated.

I profiled the above and here's what it yielded:

```
Mon Jun 30 18:33 2014 Time and Allocation Profiling Report  (Final)

   h99 +RTS -p -RTS

total time  =        1.29 secs   (1292 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
total alloc = 2,720,050,200 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE  MODULE  %time %alloc

main         Main     95.6  100.0
isPalindrome Main      4.4    0.0

                                                          individual     inherited
COST CENTRE     MODULE                  no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

MAIN            MAIN                     43           0    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
 CAF            Main                     85           0    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
  main          Main                     86           1   95.6  100.0   100.0  100.0
   isPalindrome Main                     87           2    4.4    0.0     4.4    0.0
 CAF            GHC.Conc.Signal          84           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF            GHC.IO.Encoding          77           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF            GHC.IO.Encoding.Iconv    75           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF            GHC.IO.Handle.FD         68           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF            GHC.Show                 63           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
```

from which I infer that the problem is with `last xs` which could require the whole `xs` to be computed. If so, is there a workaround? Or is just the implementation of `[a..b]` that is 
greedy?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you surmise, `last xs` is the problem - it'll take linear time in the length of the list, and force the entire list to be generated immediately (`[a..b]` is lazy, as with Haskell lists in general). So your `isPalindrome` function will be quadratic time in total.

For a naive implementation, I would start with `xs == reverse xs`, which has the right asymptotic behaviour (linear) but a relatively high constant factor, and will end up having two entire copies of the list in memory at the point that `reverse` gets to the end of the list and starts producing results.

You can probably improve on that approach somewhat by looking at the `length` and then splitting the list at the halfway point, or maybe doing something cleverer in a single pass.

However I think for substantially better behaviour, you'd need to switch data structures - I'd look at something like [`Data.Deque`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dequeue-0.1.5/docs/Data-Dequeue.html) or [`Data.Sequence`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.2.0.1/docs/Data-Sequence.html).

Comment: Ha, you again! Thanks for answering my Haskell questions. Indeed it seems that `Data.Dequeue` is a better data structure for this implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the `last xs`, as you suspect. Suggestion: before you do any recursion, split the string at the midpoint*, and reverse the second half. Then you're comparing the first character of both strings each time you recurse. *If the strings of odd length, both strings should include the middle character.

Answer (score 1):

A bunch of interesting palindrome functions were suggested on [this reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/292g4z/algorithm_critique_requested/):

Naive

```
palindrome list = reverse list == list
```

Pointfree

```
palindrome = liftM2 (==) reverse id
```

Applicative

```
palindrome = (==) <$> reverse <*> id
```

Monadic

```
palindrome = reverse >>= (==)
```