# Haskell Recursion Function (guards required)

Tags: haskell, recursion, palindrome

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my implementation of this Haskell palindrome checker? Note: Before calling this on the the input string, the string is "cleaned" to get rid of case discrepancies and any non-alphabet characters.

```
checkPalindromeClean :: [Char] -> Bool
checkPalindromeClean inpString
    | length inpString == 0 = True
    | length inpString == 1 = True
    | head inpString == last inpString = checkPalindromeClean (init (tail inpString))
    otherwise False
```

Here is the (cryptic) error message I am receiving:

```
jdoodle.hs:43:42: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool -> Bool -> Bool’
                  with actual type ‘Bool’
    • The function ‘checkPalindromeClean’
      is applied to three value arguments,
        but its type ‘[Char] -> Bool’ has only one
      In the expression:
        checkPalindromeClean (init (tail inpString)) otherwise False
      In an equation for ‘checkPalindromeClean’:
          checkPalindromeClean inpString
            | length inpString == 0 = True
            | length inpString == 1 = True
            | head inpString == last inpString
            = checkPalindromeClean (init (tail inpString)) otherwise False
   |
43 |     | head inpString == last inpString = checkPalindromeClean (init (tail inpString))
   |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
```

Comment: Can you explain `checkPalindromeClean (init (tail inpString))`?  And don't you need to remove the tail AND the head?

Comment: @ScottHunter: it does remove the head and the tail: `tail` will remove the first item, whereas `init` removes the last one.

Comment: syntax error. last line should be:
| otherwise = False

Answer (score 4):

`otherwise` is a condition too (it is an alias of `True`), and therefore should be used as a guard as well, so:

```
checkPalindromeClean :: [Char] -> Bool
checkPalindromeClean inpString
    | length inpString == 0 = True
    | length inpString == 1 = True
    | head inpString == last inpString = checkPalindromeClean (init (tail inpString))
    | otherwise = False
```

Using [**`length :: [a] -> Int`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:length), [**`init :: [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:init) and [**`last :: [a] -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:last) all run in *(n)*, therefore the algorithm will run in *(n<sup>2</sup>)*, which is not very efficient.

Comment: With regards to runtime efficiency, this question may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24495135/haskell-formidably-long-palindrome-check